# Device orientation - headtracker

Tags: javascript, device-orientation

```
  if(window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
            var alpha = event.alpha;
     }
```

So, I need to get value from 0-180 for servo. I have thought about something like this

```
  alpha = 90+ (absolutely_first_value_from_event.alpha-event.alpha);
```

And my problem is, that I don't know how to get only first value from event.alpha ... code isn't complete becouse I just need help with getting and storing first value from event.alpha

Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar.

```
function oneTime (event) {
    var alpha = event.alpha;
    var beta = event.beta;
    var gamma = event.gamma;    
  alert('Device Orientation Coordinates = ' + alpha + ' : ' + beta + ' : ' + gamma);
  window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', oneTime);
}
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', oneTime);
```

The event listener removes itself after the first event.
Have a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/ to better understand what exactly is happening.

Be sure to have a look at [full-tilt.js](https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt) as well as [gyronorm.js](https://github.com/dorukeker/gyronorm.js) if you need to be more specific about your values.

Also **this is quite important** and comes the from Google Chrome console:

> The **deviceorientation event** is deprecated on insecure origins, and
>   support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching
>   your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details. (index):141
>
> The **devicemotion event** is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed
>   in the future. You should consider switching your application to a
>   secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more
>   details.

Meaning if your site is hosted via HTTP and you make use of these events they *soon* won't work on Chrome unless you serve the site via HTTP**S**. Deal with it.